# Issue with fp "missing number" macro

Tags: fp

I write an fp macro that calculates the distance between frets on a guitar neck:

```
\def\ScaleLength{25.5}
\def\ScaleFactor{0.1}

\def\FretDist#1{\FPmul\resulta{-1}{#1}%
\FPdiv\resulta{\resulta}{12}%
\FPpow\resulta{2}{\resulta}%
\FPsub\resulta{1}{\resulta}%
\FPmul\resulta{25.5}{\resulta}
\FPmul\resulta{\resulta}{\ScaleFactor}
\resulta
}
```

And putting things like

```
\FretDist{3}
```

In latex gives the proper floating point value.

When I try to use that value in a package like

```
\put(3,\FretDist{3}){\circle{3}}
```

I get an error "Missing number, treated as zero", yet if I do

```
\put(3,3){\circle{3}}
```

works fine

Comment: Please consider assembling your code snippets in a "Minimum Working Example" (MWE) of LaTeX code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xfp`, that works expandably and allows a neater syntax for the operations. The number of decimal digits is not the same as provided by `fp`, but it shouldn't matter for most applications (including this one).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\usepackage{fp} % for the old method
\usepackage{xfp} % for the new method

\newcommand\ScaleLength{25.5}
\newcommand\ScaleFactor{0.1}

\newcommand\FretDist[1]{\FPmul\resulta{-1}{#1}%
\FPdiv\resulta{\resulta}{12}%
\FPpow\resulta{2}{\resulta}%
\FPsub\resulta{1}{\resulta}%
\FPmul\resulta{\ScaleLength}{\resulta}
\FPmul\resulta{\resulta}{\ScaleFactor}
\resulta
}

\newcommand{\xFretDist}[1]{%
  \fpeval{
    \ScaleLength*\ScaleFactor*(1-exp(-(#1/12)*ln(2)))
  }
}

\begin{document}

\FretDist{9}

\xFretDist{9}

\FretDist{3} % now \resulta contains the value

\xFretDist{3}

\bigskip

\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(3,\resulta){\circle{3}}
\end{picture}}

\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(3,\xFretDist{3}){\circle{3}}
\end{picture}}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the pictures are the same.

[image]

#### Old answer

You can't use `\FretDist{3}` as argument to `\put`, because this commands expects a number and not a whole set of instructions to print it. Change the definition of `\FretDist` as follows

```
\def\FretDist#1{\FPmul\resulta{-1}{#1}%
\FPdiv\resulta{\resulta}{12}%
\FPpow\resulta{2}{\resulta}%
\FPsub\resulta{1}{\resulta}%
\FPmul\resulta{25.5}{\resulta}
\FPmul\resulta{\resulta}{\ScaleFactor}
}
```

so that, after calling it, you'll have `\resulta` available for usage as a number:

```
\FretDist{3} % store the number in \resulta
\put(3,\resulta){\circle{3}}
```

Comment: This works but takes more work when you are looping over a variable. Counters and dimensions cannot be used as arguments for fretdist so I had to use one of fp's registers which means I had to add code to treat it like a counter.

Answer (score 0):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, tricky argument expansion can be replaced by intuitive function composition, which is similar to other programmming languages such as `Lua`.
The evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{functional}

\def\ScaleLength{25.5}
\def\ScaleFactor{0.1}

\PrgNewFunction \FretDist {m} {%
  \FpEval{(1-2^(((-1)*(#1))/12))*\ScaleLength*\ScaleFactor}%
}

\PrgNewFunction \FunPut {mmm} {\put(#1,#2){#3}}

\begin{document}

\FretDist{3}

\begin{picture}(40,30)
\put(3,0.405714141103028){\circle{3}}
\end{picture}

\begin{picture}(40,30)
\FunPut{3}{\FretDist{3}}{\circle{3}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```