# macros that won't accept other macros as arguments

Tags: macros, fp

I'm trying to pass a counter to a macro that uses macros from the `fp` package.

I can pass hard coded values and `\results` from the `fp` package BUT if I pass the counter it complains that it is not a valid floating point value.

Is there any way to make this is work? There should be no diference between `\cmd{1}` and `\cmd{\count0}` as logically and mathematically when `\count0` is 1.

I'm not sure what is going on behind the scenes but there should be some way to get it to work. This will save me trouble of having to create a `\result` variable that follows the counter which adds unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Perhaps [what is the proper method of accessing a counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter) will help.  But, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I've tried all logical combinations of \the, \value, \arabic, \count0, {\count0} and I always get an \endcsname error. I think it has to do with how fp handles the arguments more than anything.

Comment: Without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), it is really difficult to help you. So, please start from scratch (or reduce from your full code) to compose a really small example to show the problem.  Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At face value, or as the current question stands, it seems like you're merely interested in passing counter values to "some command", which may even be macros supplied by the [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp).

Here is a minimal example of passing counter values to the `fp` package macros:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\begin{document}
\newcounter{count0} \newcounter{test}
\setcounter{count0}{5} \setcounter{test}{6}
\csname thecount0\endcsname \par
\thetest \par
\FPeval\result{clip(2*3+5*6)}\result \par
\FPeval\result{clip(2*3+\csname thecount0\endcsname*6)}\result \par
\FPeval\result{clip(2*3+5*\thetest)}\result
\end{document}
```

Note that if you're using `count0` as a counter name, value extraction is not as simple as saying `\thecount0`, since macro definitions with numerals need special care. Also, `\value{count0}` (internal representation of `count0`) may be different from `\csname thecount0\endcsname` (the typesetting of `count0`), which may be different from `\arabic{count0}` (a fixed `\arabic` representation of `count0`).

Counters *without* numerals in their name are handled much easier (like `test`) in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect that a macro such as `\FretDist` that you defined in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48198/issue-with-fp-missing-number-macro) is fed to another macro so that `\FretDist{3}` is interpreted as the number resulting from the calculation.

An instruction such as

```
\FPmul\resulta{-1}{3}
```

tells LaTeX to store the result of the multiplication in the macro `\resulta`. So you can't expect that

```
\cmd{\FPmul\resulta{-1}{3}}
```

is equivalent to calling `\cmd{-3}`, nor hiding the calculation in another macro, say

```
\newcommand{\mycalc}[1]{\FPmul\resulta{-1}{#1}}
```

and calling `\cmd{\mycalc{3}}` would help. Also

```
\newcommand{\mycalc}[1]{\FPmul\resulta{-1}{#1}\resulta}
```

would not work, because `\cmd` must know what number to use, not the process to getting it. Depending on the definition of `\cmd`, saying

```
\FPmul\resulta{-1}{3}\cmd{\resulta}
```

might work. Notice that `\resulta` is *not* something to which `\the`, `\value` or `\arabic` might apply, nor is your `\FretDist` macro.

Answer (score 1):

Without a MWE is not obvious to find a correct answer

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fp,tikz}
\newcount\cnt  
\newcommand\addline[2][]{%
\FPeval\resulta{#2*#2}
\FPeval\resultb{2*#2}  
\tikz \draw[#1] (0,0)--(\resulta,\resultb);}  

\begin{document}

\cnt=2 %
\addline[red,thick]{\the\cnt}
\end{document}
```